# Running scripts in trusted HTML with Angular 2

Tags: angular, embed, html-sanitizing

**What I've got**

I'm building a personal blog app with Angular 2. I have blog posts in a JSON file which is served from my server.

```
// Single post route
apiRouter.route("/post/:id")
    // Get a specific post
    .get((req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        let post = blogData.posts.find(post => post.date === Number(req.params.id));
        res.json(post);
    })
);
```

Individual entries in the JSON blog data file look like this:

```
"posts": [
  {
    "title": "Some Post's Title",
    "body": "Some post's body.",
    "date": 1481582451092,
    "headerImageName": ""
  },
  { ... }, ...
]
```

In my webapp I want to have a single "Blog Post" typescript component that displays an individual post when a visitor is on a route which maps to a single post.

I've defined a simple post data class like this:

```
export class PostData {
    body: string;
    date: number;
    imageFileName: string;
    title: string;
}
```

When displaying the post body I pass it through this pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "trustPipe"
})
export class TrustPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(@Inject(DomSanitizer) private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

In order to display it, I've written the following component:

```
import { TrustPipe } from "./trust.pipe";

@Component({
    selector: "active-component",
    template: `
    <div class="card">
        <div *ngIf="post">
            <div class="card-title">
                <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
            </div>
            <div [innerHTML]="post.body | trustPipe"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    styleUrls: ["styles/post.component.css", "styles/card.css"]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  
    // Post is a superclass to PostData, it just provides
    // some helper functions on the base class, such as truncation
    // and a means of formatting dates
    post: Post;

    constructor(
        @Inject(BlogService) private blogService: BlogService,
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            const id: number = +params["id"];
            this.blogService
                .getPost(id)
                .then(data => this.post = new Post(data));
        });
    }
}
```

**What Does this all do?**

With that out of the way, the important takeaway is that I have some variant string (JSON for a post's body) which represents a section of HTML I'd like to insert as a child to some DOM element. To do so I used the `[innerHTML]` attribute and wrote an Angular Pipe that uses `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` for trusting the string as safe HTML.

**What happens?**

Script tags don't execute. Say I've written a blog post which has something embedded in it - in my case it's likely a Github Gist, Instagram photo, or Google photos album. I found that this is true - script tags don't execute - and a means of using Javascript to [circumvent it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39473833/4785629), but I want to know if angular has a means of inserting HTML like I'm trying. I have seen usage of [`ComponentFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/4785629) but I don't know if this is what I want. I'm guessing this will also stop me from using `routerLinks` in my post's bodies. I could write a child component for the post body, but then how do I dynamically swap out templates?

**Questions**

a) Why does Angular stop scripts from running?

b) Any other means to get scripts to run?

c) Should I use a different design pattern for this - serving posts as HTML for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 2):

a) Security and in particular protection against XSS - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

b) Yes but but be very careful - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#bypass-security-apis

Have you tried bypassing the security apis in your component instead of a pipe? Also what security context are you using?

c) Can you parse the blog post and save it in a safe format or do you really want to allow any js to run on your website?

Comment: a) Ahh yes duh. XSS - I've studied that in my security engineering course. b) Yep, that's what I'm using, still no script execution. c) I'm the one writing the posts, so I can do anything. What do you suggest?

Comment: a) it is as simple as that b) Can you post the code where you are bypassing the security apis? c) Sorry I don't know :)

Comment: Added in the pipe transform to the original question