# How to execute any javascript in template after render? Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I got a page where I try to insert HTML with scripts.

```
import {
    Component,
    AfterViewInit,
    ViewChild,
    ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'menu-blocks-menupage',
    template: `<div class="menuArticle" #dataContainer (click)="logit()" padding></div>`
})
export class MenuBlocksMenuPage implements AfterViewInit {
    menu: MenuItem;
    //Контейнер для вставки
    @ViewChild('dataContainer') dataContainer: ElementRef;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>" + "alert('123123213');" + "</script>";
    }
}
```

HTML with script tags is inserted after render, but nothing happens. What is wrong?

**ANSWER IS:**

```js
ngAfterViewInit()
      {
        const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<script type='text/javascript'>" +
  "alert('123123213');" +
  "</script>");
        this.dataContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(fragment);
      }
```

Comment: **script** tags are not executed when inserted via **innerHTML** - see a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473049/angular2-dynamically-insert-script-tag) - The answer explains that you can append a html fragment.

Comment: and why would you insert a script tag to execute javascript rather than just execute the javascript code directly?

Comment: Because I want to use API to request json with user's html which can contain anything what ever they want.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.