# Google Signin with Angular

Tags: google-signin

I have a very simple page in Angular2, which contains a google Sign in button. Here is my code :

**login.html**

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }
</script>

<div class="g-signin2 google-connect" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

**login.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
// This code simply loads the JS after the page is rendered, since it doesn't work with only the script tag on the top of the HTML
```

The button is working very well, I can sign in perfectly, but I can't get the user informations. The onSignIn function is not triggering.

I've tried to change the data-onsuccess by multiple directives, I created functions inside my controller, or let the one google provides in my HTML, but I have no output on my console. I can't manage to retrieved the data of a connection. I'd juste like to get basic informations of an user (ID and mail). I can't use Angular2 plugins since i'm developing under Ionic.
Thank you in avance for any help :)

Comment: I was searching on the same topic and found this ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458346/need-to-insert-script-tag-in-
angular-2