# Angular 4 external script

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have a script that i need to add that will add html element to permit me to send a form and i cannot find a way to add it perfectly.

I tried the bypasssecuritytrusthtml (bypasssecuritytrustscript too) and the second answer of this post ([Need to insert Script tag in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458346/need-to-insert-script-tag-in-angular-2)), but nothing work.

In the first case, it never shows or say it is sanitize. In the other case, it only shows if i reload precicely the page where the form is, so if i go from another route it does not show.

The part that i need to add is a Pipedrive form that looks like this:

```
<div class="pipedriveWebForms" data-pd-webforms="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/**id of the form**">
    <script src="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/webforms.min.js"></script>
</div>
```