# Import external js script into Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I was trying to implement this [widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) to my Angular app. For the second part I was able to create a custom js file in my assets folder, create a .d.ts file for it and successfully imported the function in my component.

But for the first part:

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?5" data-telegram-login="samplebot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
```

If I do it with plain HTML and js, it will fetch from the website and generate a login button. Yet I tried simply pasting it into my component's HTML, it does not get rendered. As it is not a function nor a variable, I am not sure how can I place it into a specific div in the component.

Please help.

Comment: Are you able to show how you tried adding this into your component's HTML? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to insert Script tag in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458346/need-to-insert-script-tag-in-angular-2)

Comment: @OliverRadini I simply put the quoted script tag into a div, no special stuff.

Comment: @lumio I tried DomSanitizer, no luck. And tried the "script-hack" method, I see that from "Network" of devtool it finally fetch the js file from telegram.org but the button still does not show up.