# Angular: Why does this code does not result in an alert?

Tags: angular, xss

`<h3 _ngcontent-c4="" class="project-name">"Sometest"</h3><script>alert('xss');</script><h3>test</h3>`

I tried to use an XSS vulnerability in my own project. But it somehow does not get triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem. You are not closing the `script` tag properly.

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `/` from the script end tag. (Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo)

Comment: Angular probably protects you by default of this kind of injection.

Answer (score 0):

`script` tags are stripped of from component markup. Its done by `HTMLSanitizer`. This is done as XSS prevention feature.

> Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is
>   inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style,
>   class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes
>   untrusted values.

It is possible but discouraged to inject untrusted content

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904601/1527544

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90