# How can I include the Telegram login widget in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to include the [Telegram login widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) in my Angular application. For this, you have to include the following script:

```html
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?5"
  data-telegram-login="bot_name" data-size="large"
  data-auth-url="https://myurl.example/api/telegram"
  data-request-access="write"></script>
```

Embedding scripts in Angular templates is [not allowed](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss), it will just be removed. (However, it is possible to include a script tag via [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904601/4694994).)

Is there a non-hacky way of including this widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not rendering `script` tags in template code is indeed a design choice from Angular team.

The way to do it is thus:

1. **Add your scripts to index.html** - only relevant if it makes sense to load the script globally.
2. Or **Add your script programmatically**. The post you refer to can be a solution, but brings in additional complication because it takes the input data from template code. A shorter solution is given here, when you're happy with inputing the parameters from the code-side (and the full issue is instructive too): [Github issue #4903](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903#issuecomment-459438083). Warning though: adding to the `head` is not suitable unless you remove it in `OnDestroy`. Prefer adding in the right DOM element of your component.

Answer (score 3):

I created the following component for the Telegram login widget:

The component creates the script tag dynamically and adds the callback function `loginViaTelegram(user)`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-telegram-login-widget',
  template: `    
<div #script style.display="none">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./telegram-login-widget.component.css']
})
export class TelegramLoginWidgetComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('script', {static: true}) script: ElementRef;

  convertToScript() {
    const element = this.script.nativeElement;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?5';
    script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', environment.telegramBotName);
    script.setAttribute('data-size', 'large');
    // Callback function in global scope
    script.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'loginViaTelegram(user)');
    script.setAttribute('data-request-access', 'write');
    element.parentElement.replaceChild(script, element);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.convertToScript();
  }

}
```

I added the callback function `loginViaTelegram` to the `window` object (global space) in a dedicated service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TelegramLoginService {    
  init() {
    window['loginViaTelegram'] = loginData => this.loginViaTelegram(loginData);
  }

  private loginViaTelegram(loginData: TelegramLoginData) {
    // If the login should trigger view changes, run it within the NgZone.
    this.ngZone.run(() => process(loginRequest));
  }
}
```

Comment: for me it gives ```Refused to frame 'https://oauth.telegram.org/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://host.de".```

Comment: @AidosOmurzakov Did you do this step? "send the `/setdomain` command to `@Botfather` to link your website's domain" https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#linking-your-domain-to-the-bot

Comment: @KimKern What is ```TelegramLoginData``` and ```loginRequest```?